# Resetting to __noproxy__

Tags: terminal, rhel, proxy

I am trying to download the EL repository for RedHat7.  Using the instructions given on the ELRepo homepage, I ran into the following error:

```
rpm --import https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
curl: (5) Failed connect to wwwproxy.(company).com:(port) ; Connection timed out
error: https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org: import read failed(2).
```

I don't want to use a proxy because I took the machine home, and there is no proxy set up here.  Unfortunately, when I try to export a different 'null' proxy, the computer is failing to resolve the issue:

```
rpm --import https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:1080; Connection refused
error: https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org: import read failed(2).
```

I get similar issues when I try to export `''` and `__noproxy__` to my proxy settings.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the proxy is defined in environment variables. You can unset all proxy variables with this command:

```
for var in $(env | sed -n '/_proxy=/s/=.*//p'); do unset $var; done
```

Comment: After unsetting the proxy using your command, and doing my rpm import command returns: `curl: could not resolve proxy: https_proxy; Name or service not known error'

Comment: Quite pedandic. Maybe this helps: `export no_proxy='*'`